# "Выход в переулок X" или всё-таки "на переулок X"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как всё-таки правильно? Большинство за "в", но хочется быть полностью уверенным. И действительно ли правильно говорить "вышел ***в*** (например, Армянский) переулок"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словосочетание со словом *вышел* говорит о перемещении из одного пространства в другое (вышел из комнаты, чтобы попасть *в другую*), и это правильно, если выход состоялся в переулок, а не в его начало или конец. Тогда употребим более подходящий предлог *К*: *вышел к переулку* (выход на Кадашёвскую наб. к Лаврушинскому пер.).

Comment: Точно, shampar, как я не догадался, не вспомнил про "к"!

Answer (score 2):

Можно было бы посомневаться, есть ли различия в предлогах для тротуара и проезжей части переулка (в английском языке такое есть для "улицы") - встречается "на" в сообщениях о ДТП, но нет - статистика неумолима: в "нац. корпусе" по письменным документам счёт 543:2 в пользу предлога "**в**". При этом один из двух источников - от автора, публиковавшегося за рубежом, второй - мемуары актрисы.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Вы именно о выходе? Можно, например, это применить к выходу из метро?

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел о "выходе на переулок": **все** случаи в "корпусе" относятся к _направлению (ориентации)_ окна (калитки) на переулок. Думаю, что к выходу из метро, обозначаемому в справочной надписи как направление в сторону переулка, это можно применить.

Comment: Надеюсь, Александр, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **"вышел в переулок".** Здесь предлог **в** обусловлен традицией.
И это вполне объяснимо. Ведь "переулок" - это  короткая, узкая улица. Пр.: Глухой переулок.
А предлог "в" как раз и употреблаятся с закрытыми пространствами.

Вот что говорится **в Справочнике по стилистике и литературной правке, Розенталь, Д. Э.**

Употребление предлога **в** пространственном значении **связано с представлением об ограниченном пространстве, при отсутствии этого значения употребляется предлог на.**

> Ср.: машины стояли во дворе (окруженное забором или домами пространство) – дети играли на дворе (вне дома; ср.: на дворе сегодня холодно).
>
> Иногда сказывается **исторически сложившаяся традиция**; ср.: в деревне – на хуторе, в селе – первый на селе работник; в учреждении – на предприятии, **в переулке – на улице;** ср. также: в комбинате бытового обслуживания – на мясокомбинате.

Comment: Спасибо, только я спрашивал в первую очередь про "выход", а не "вышел". С выходом так же, вы считаете? "Не большая короткая" как-то очень странно звучит.))) Можно предположить, что вы имели в виду "небольшая" слитно, но и тогда, по-моему, одно из этих слов лишнее, ведь "короткая и узкая" — это и есть небольшая.

Comment: Выход, вход, выйти, зайти ***в переулок***.

Comment: Вы правы: "небольшая" здесь лишняя.